# Orthogonal transformation of a set of points to positive orthant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations, orthogonal-matrices

Let $x_1,x_2\ldots,x_n$ are vectors from $\mathbb{R}^d$. Also assume that $x_i^{\top}x_j \geq 0$ for all $i,j=1,2,\ldots,n$. I am wondering if there is an orthogonal matrix $W$ such that the entries of $Wx_i$'s are non-negative for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.

I can prove the statement for $d=2$. Any ideas or counterexample for the cases when $d\geq 3$ will be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll find that a circular, right-angled cone $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$, say the one defined by $z \geq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, cannot be fit into any octant, even though $u^Tv \geq 0$ for all $u,v \in C$.

Comment: What a beautiful example!  I checked the angle of the main diagonal of a cube with the edges and the small diagonal, about $54^{\circ}$, and $35^{\circ}$.  Come to think about it, why all figures on the sphere of diameter at most $\frac{\pi}{2}$ would be all contained in a special one of same diameter, that does not happen in the plane either.

Comment: Many thanks for the nice example :)

Comment: No problem, and I liked your explanation in terms of the corresponding figures on a sphere! When I was convincing myself of this I was imagining interecting with a plane away from the origin (basically projectivizing) but your idea makes things more clear.